# jQuery Add Key Value Pair to an Empty Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

In jQuery, I can add multiple attributes to an element like so...

```
var input = $('<input/>').attr({ type : 'text', value : 'New Value'});
```

My question is, how can I achieve this using a variable like this...

```
var input = $('<input/>').attr(inputAttr);
```

I was under the assumption that `inputAttr` should be an object and that I could add to that object.  I must be mistaken.  This was one of my many attempts to make this happen.

```
var inputAttr = {};
inputAttr.add({ type: 'text' });
inputAttr.add({ value : 'New Value' });
```

I also tried like this....

```
var inputAttr = {};
inputAttr.add('type: text');
inputAttr.add('value : New Value');
```

I thought maybe `inputAttr` should be an array instead, which seems to output a correct string but not sure how to make it an object (which I think it should be).

```
var inputAttr = [];
inputAttr.push('type: text');
inputAttr.push('value : New Value');

// Then added object brackets like so
var input = $('<input/>').attr({inputAttr});
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Object properties are just accessed by name. It is not an array.

```
var inputAttr = {};
inputAttr.type = 'text';
inputAttr.value = 'New Value';

var input = $('<input/>').attr(inputAttr);
```

If you want to access them indirectly via keys it is like a dictionary:

```
var inputAttr = {};
inputAttr["type"] = 'text';
inputAttr["value"] = 'New Value';
```

Comment: Fiddle makes me late for 36 seconds :)

Comment: @Regent: A Fiddle shouild not be needed on something this basic :)

Comment: Is it necessary to put the brackets around the variable here `var input = $('<input/>').attr({inputAttr});` Also, both of your answers will add to the object? And I can retrieve like so... `alert(inputAttr["type"])`?

Comment: Sorry typo - not needed (cut & paste from your original) :)

Comment: Yes you can access via `object["keyname"]` syntax also. Handy if the name is in a string variable.

Comment: And I can alternatively retrieve like this... `alert(inputAttr.type)`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie adding a fiddle is a like a habit already, you know :) But you have mentioned `inputAttr["type"]` - it's definitely worth for one more +1.

Comment: Yes. Javascript objects are dynamic. You can reference properties that exist (or don't exist) by name. If they don't exists you get an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 8):

Key-value for `object` can be set in this way:

```
var inputAttr = {};
inputAttr.type = 'text';
inputAttr.value = 'New Value';
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L6pdxjd/).